Example of non supersingular Weil number
This question aims mainly at some misconception I may have regarding the formalism of Weil numbers. These are defined as some algebraic integers with a fixed complex modulus under all possible embeddings into $\mathbb C$.
More precisely, let us fix $q$ a power of some prime number $p$. A $q$-Weil number (later, $q$ will be implicit) is some algebraic number $\alpha$ in an unspecified field such that, for all embeddings $\iota: \mathbb Q[\alpha]\hookrightarrow \mathbb C$, we have $|\iota(\alpha)| = \sqrt q$.
I have read in a paper that a supersingular Weil number is defined to be a Weil number of the form $\xi \sqrt q$ for some root of unity $\xi$. These are interesting since an abelian variety defined over $\mathbb F_q$ is supersingular if and only if the eigenvalues of the Frobenius (acting on the $\ell$-rational Tate module for some $\ell \not = p$) are supersingular Weil numbers.
However, so far when reading about Weil numbers, I always imagined that they would all look like $\xi \sqrt q$ for some $\xi$. Well, the idea being that in $\mathbb C$, numbers of these form are exactly the algebraic numbers of modulus $\sqrt q$.
Thus, I need to get rid of the idea of algebraic numbers being embedded into $\mathbb C$ in order to grasp this notion. An algebraic number then is just the (abstract) algebraic notion of a root of some irreducible monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Likewise, a root of unity is an algebraic number killed by a polynomial of the form $X^n - 1$ for some $n$, and $\sqrt q$ is a notation for a root of $X^2 - q$. Then, I am guessing the following characterization:

An algebraic number is a supersingular Weil number if and only if its minimal polynomial is a factor of $X^{2n} - q^n$ for some $n$.

Is this the correct interpretation for the definition of a supersingular Weil number?
If so, I am asking for an example of Weil number which is not killed by any of the polynomials as above ; in other words, I'm looking for an irreducible monic polynomial with integer coefficients, all of whose complex roots have modulus $\sqrt q$, and which is not a factor of $X^{2n} - q^n$ for all $n$.
Does a simple example exist? Feel free to give specific values to $q$ if it helps writing down an example.

Futher to the previous comments, take an abelian variety you know to not be supersingular... now compute its $L$-polynomial. The above example is for an elliptic curve (over $\mathbb{F}_p$) with trace of Frobenius $a \neq 0$.
